# Apache: Run standard-PHP side by side with Fast-CGI

Tags: php, apache-2.2, cgi, configuration

I'd like to run a server that 'delegates' certain requests to a C++-Script via FastCGI - how can I configure Apache to do so? It would just be enough to redirect requests to a specific page I could define in some config-file, but unfortunately I don't know which and how.

I'd be glad if someone could help - Thanks.

Comment: Probably better for ServerFault

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to go, is to simply use a different suffix for the "special" pages and use an `AddHandler` directive to your apache configuration. Assuming the "special" pages have a suffix of `.fcgi` you would need

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
```

Comment: The suffix-solution is definitely possible - didn't expect it to be that simple! I'll try it out, thanks for your help.